# What new community roles should we ask for?

Tags: feature-request

[Help us identify new roles for community members](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384169/help-us-identify-new-roles-for-community-members?cb=1)

The above meta question asks what new roles are needed on Stack Exchange sites - that is, other than moderator.

I've made a suggestion that we should ask for a role that can award large bonuses to users who ask good questions or make good answers on important and neglected topics.  If you think I'm right, please go over there and [upvote it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384207/301090).

If you think that proposal needs tweaking, I'm open to suggestions. If you want to ask for something else, put an answer below and we can hash it out (we can ask for more than one thing, of course).

Comment: you've linked to an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/259135). Would it make more sense to link to the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384169/259135), or do I misunderstand the intent?

Comment: There's a link to the question at the top there. I'm hoping to canvass some support for my suggestion, but also to encourage others to make different ones if they want to. If you feel both those things shouldn't be in one post, I'm happy to make a second question. Question and answer is sometimes a bit of an awkward fit for the discussions we need to have on meta.

Comment: When I clicked on the top link, I was taken to your answer, not to the question.  I have upvoted and think your suggestion is brilliant.  (I think it has more to do with "diversity" than with "global", but like you, I'm not sure what the title _should_ be). Well done

Comment: Thanks for the words of support. I've fixed the link now. I think we need to speak up for humanities-related stacks as their needs can be overlooked. And, to put it mildly, the past few years has shown us that the world needs the humanities - technological innovations alone can't solve all of the world's problems.